# Listening to Nusach During the Three Weeks

Tags: music, tisha-bav, nine-days, three-weeks

We're not allowed to listen to music during the Three Weeks, Nine Days, or Tisha B'Av, but are you permitted to listen to nusach like chazzanus or niggunim?

Comment: Nusach, Chazzonus, and Niggunim are all different, with different halachos.

Comment: "We're not allowed to listen to music during the Three Weeks, Nine Days, or Tisha B'Av" Source?

Comment: I listened to weekday Shacharit Nusach this morning for about 6 minutes along with some rabbis and laypeople, and no one there seemed to have a problem with it.

Comment: I think that there are 2 aspects that would probably allow this. The prohibition of music during the 3 weeks is identical to those for the *sefirah* period, as far as I know. I assume that all the music that you mentioned is "a Cappella", in which case, it's probably allowable. (There are numerous MY questions on this topic from what I recall; of course verify your case with your rav.) The other aspect, is that if you're listening to this for a job, such as you need to listen to nusach tapes for an upcoming Rosh Hashanna job, then, there's probably greater leniency to let you do this.

Comment: FWIW, you have a redundancy. The "Three Weeks" includes the other 2 occasions that you listed.

Comment: There are definitely those who permit chazzanus, even with musical accompaniment, on the grounds that the music is only there to serve as an insignificant backdrop to the voice, and that the human voice is ok to listen to as long as it's not being made to sound like a musical instrument. That should cover your other categories as well. Don't remember sources, so leaving as comment.

Comment: @Jay Even modern Chazzonus recordings (Moshe Stern, Yakov Stark, and to a lesser extent, Oid Yosef Chai, come to mind)? They have quite a significant amount of music, more than just a backdrop IMO.